# Guidance on getting desired SQL results

Tags: sql

Thanks to the help on my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73551189/nested-sql-query-guidance/73551384#73551384), I now have one final step to fully grasp this method of querying for my problem.

Given these two tables:

`airlines_detail`:

| airplane_id | airline_id | total_seats |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2187 | 425 | 260 |
| 4361 | 747 | 290 |
| 3478 | 747 | 270 |
| 7292 | 425 | 250 |
| 5833 | 425 | 310 |
| 3472 | 425 | 300 |
| 4472 | 747 | 290 |
| 2624 | 425 | 320 |

`Bookings`:

| airplane_id | booked |
| --- | --- |
| 2187 | 40 |
| 4361 | 30 |
| 4361 | 10 |
| 5833 | 30 |
| 4361 | 30 |
| 2624 | 30 |
| 4472 | 40 |
| 4472 | 40 |
| 2624 | 10 |
| 7292 | 20 |
| 2187 | 20 |
| 4472 | 30 |
| 3478 | 20 |
| 3472 | 40 |
| 4472 | 30 |
| 4472 | 10 |
| 4361 | 20 |
| 3478 | 30 |
| 2187 | 30 |
| 2187 | 10 |

I need to get this result:

| airline_id | airplanes |
| --- | --- |
| 425 | 7292 |
| 747 | 4361 |

The result is the `airplane_id` whose `SUM` of empty seats is closest to the `AVG` number of empty seats per each `airline_id` (in this case, there's only 425 and 747 to worry about).

So, we would need to find the `AVG` of `SUM(empty_seats) GROUP BY airline_id`, then compare the `SUM(empty_seats) GROUP BY airplane_id` for each airline, and return a table that shows the airplanes that are closest to their respective airline's average of empty seats.

For airline with id 425 the average number of empty seats are 242. Therefore the airplane which is closest to this average is 7292.

Equipped with the answer from the previous question in getting the sum of empty seats for each plane, I'm hoping this next step is a simple one for a guru.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would start with the query you have, then use that as an intermediate result to get the averages per airline, and then rank the airplanes by how much their empty seat count deviates from their airline's average. For that ranking you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and a windowing clause (`OVER`).
Finally, select the rows in that result that are ranked first.

For this chain of building upon previous results, it is handy to use the `WITH` syntax:

```
WITH base as (
    SELECT
        a.airplane_id,
        a.airline_id,
        a.total_seats - SUM(b.booked) AS empty_seats
    FROM
        airlines_detail a
    LEFT JOIN bookings b
        ON
            a.airplane_id = b.airplane_id
    GROUP BY  
        a.airplane_id,
        a.airline_id
), average as (
    SELECT
        airline_id,
        AVG(empty_seats) avg_empty_seats
    FROM
        base
    GROUP BY
        airline_id
), ranked as (
    SELECT
        b.airplane_id,
        b.airline_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY b.airline_id 
            ORDER BY ABS(b.empty_seats - a.avg_empty_seats)
        ) rn
    FROM
        base b
    INNER JOIN average a
        ON
            a.airline_id = b.airline_id
)
SELECT
    airline_id,
    airplane_id
FROM
    ranked
WHERE
    rn = 1;
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you for the clear explanation too, that made it super easy to understand on my end. Thanks!!!